# Print x characters of a string over x lines

Tags: python

How can I write a function that prints a word over and over again, in sections of `x` letters, until `x` lines are reached. For example, the following:

```
nelio("ab",3) 
print()
nelio("aybabtu",5)
```

will print:

```
aba
bab
aba

aybab
tuayb
abtua
ybabt
uayba
```

I started by writing a program, below, that just prints the whole word `x` times, but can't figure out how to move forward from here.

```
def nelio(word,size):
    i = 0    
    while i < size:
        print(word)
        i+=1      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nelio("auto",3)
```

Comment: Check out the [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/textwrap.html) module.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't really use import in our course.

Comment: You can use word[0] to print first letter, word[1] to the second. I think you can fihmgure out the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def nelio(word,size):
    i = 0
    for line in range(size):
        for char in range(size):
            print(word[i % len(word)], end="")
            i += 1
        print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nelio("auto",3)
    print()
    nelio("ab",3) 
    print()
    nelio("aybabtu",5)
```

Output:

```
aut
oau
toa

aba
bab
aba

aybab
tuayb
abtua
ybabt
uayba
```

Answer (score 2):

A fun little way of doing this is using a generator. Normally you would just use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), but if you say you can't import, no problem:

```py
def cycle_word(word):
    while True:
        for letter in word:
            yield letter
```

And now you can use that to always get the next letter:

```py
def nelio(word, count):
    letters = cycle_word(word)
    for _ in range(count):
        new_word = ''.join(next(letters) for _ in range(count))
        print(new_word)
```

Comment: I like this one, still trying to get my head around the cycling ;)

Comment: Thanks @Bruno! Well it's a bit different from the library one, but the idea is that the generator just keeps yielding letters - whenever the word is finished, start again. Then we simply take values from that iterator according to the structure

Comment: Yes I did not realize a generator just keeps looping a list. Nice to know.

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen Not necessarily! It's the way I built it to be an infinite generator with that `while True`. A generator can also just yield 2 elements and exhaust...

Answer (score 1):

and if you do not want to deal with modulus, just expand the word first and then just do some simple slicing

```
def nelio(word, repeat):
    expanded_word = word
    while len(expanded_word) < repeat * repeat:
        expanded_word += word

    start = 0
    for _ in range(repeat):
        end = start + repeat
        print(expanded_word[start:end])
        start += repeat

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        answer = input('Give me a word, repeat [hello, 2]: ')
        word, repeat = answer.split(',')
        nelio(word, int(repeat))
```

result

```
Give me a word, repeat [hello, 2]: ab, 3
aba
bab
aba
Give me a word, repeat [hello, 2]: aybabtu, 5
aybab
tuayb
abtua
ybabt
uayba
Give me a word, repeat [hello, 2]:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def nelio(word,size):
    c=0
    i=0
    while c<size:
        str=""
        line_lenght=0
        while line_lenght<size:
            str+=word[i]
            i+=1
            i%=len(word)
            line_lenght+=1
        print(str)
        c+=1

if __name__=="__main__":
    nelio("aybabtu",5)
```